# php contact form help needed

Tags: php, html, forms

I have looked at some similar questions asked on here but not had much luck. i am currently getting this error message which is sitting above my bootstrap contact form box. the error message appears before i click submit. i am rather new to php and in need of some help. 
Edit: My hosting does have mail capabilities

> Notice: Undefined index: Lname in /web/users/m2105652/fyp/contact.php on line 7 Notice: Undefined index: email in /web/users/m2105652/fyp/contact.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined index: message in /web/users/m2105652/fyp/contact.php on line 9 Notice: Undefined variable: Fname in /web/users/m2105652/fyp/contact.php on line 13

Here is my php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

$Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
$Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "myemail@gmail.com"; // <<< change this to your own E-mail address
$subject = "Contact From My Website";
$msg = "First Name: $Fname\n" . "Last Name: $Lname\n" . "Email: $email\n" . "Message: $message";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);



?>
```

Here is my Html for the contact form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="contact.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="text-center header">Contact us</legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="Fname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="Lname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bigicon"></i></span>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your massage for us here. We will get back to you within 2 business days." rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: The notices are obvious.

Comment: the name of the field that is returend by the form submission in the $post variable is the 'name' attribute of the input, not the ID. Currently all your names are 'name'

Comment: As i said i am new to php and dont understand it fully

Comment: @Peter I think I found part of your problem. When the form submits, the `name=` attribute of each form element (eg input) become the variable names in the PHP side `$_Post[]` array.  So, `<input name="name"` over on the PHP side **is not** `$_POST['Lname']`. You have set the `input` elements' name attributes incorrectly.